# Macro to resize attached images in Outlook message

Tags: vba, image, outlook

I'd like to make an Outlook macro to resize attached JPG files that are larger than 100 KB. This is for received messages that are in the inbox, not messages that are being sent.

I have code to find attached JPG files over a set size but am not sure of how to resize them and then save the image back as an attachment.

```
Sub ResizeAttachedImage()
    Dim objMSG As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oAtt As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim oFile
    Dim extn As String
    Dim sz As Long


    'Get the source email
    Select Case Application.ActiveWindow.Class
           Case olExplorer
                Set objMSG = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
                objMSG.Display
           Case olInspector
                Set objMSG = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set oAtt = objMSG.Attachments

    For Each oFile In oAtt      'loop through the list of file attachments

        'get the file extension
        extn= Right$(oFile.FileName, Len(oFile.FileName) - InStrRev(oFile.FileName, "."))

        If LCase(extn) = "jpg" Then   'process only jpg files

            sz = oFile.Size / 1024  'file size in kb
            If sz > 100 Then

                MsgBox (oFile.FileName + " is " + Str(sz) + " KB and needs to be resized") 'oFile.FileName

                'how to resize attached images to 50%
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OOM would not let you modify an existing attachment. The only way is to delete the old attachment (`Attachment.Delete`) and add a new one back (`MailItem.Attachments.Add`). If you are modifying an embedded image attachment, make sure to reset the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F`) to its original value using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`. If `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` is missing, `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_LOCATION` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3713001F`) might also have to be set.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (disclosure: I am its author), it exposes raw attachment data as [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`AsText` / `AsArray` / `AsStream`, so the attachment would not have to be removed and then added back.